# IndexError: index is out of bounds for axis 0 python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I know that python thinks there is another number. But I have know idea how to fix this. any advice is appreciated.

```
import numpy 

test = numpy.array([9,1,3,4,8,7,2,5,6,5,-10,12,-15,19,-20,22,-53,45,43,43,23,-65,-23,46,44,67,79,5,-34,32,-56,-3,1,15,22,3])


N = 0
N1 = 3

while N < len(test):
    LOW = numpy.amin(test[N:N1])
    CLOSE = test[N1]
    HIGH = numpy.amax(test[N:N1])
    stochastic = float(CLOSE-LOW)/(HIGH-LOW)*100.00        
    print stochastic
    N1=N1+1
    N=N+1
```

Error:

```
indexError: index 36 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to put stop condition on `N1` instead of `N`:

```
while N1 < len(test):
```